# Работа декоратора patch в unittest Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, юнит-тесты

Если кратко, то не могу понять почему первый декоратор работает, а второй нет

первый:

```
@patch("balance.services.intital_services.crypto")
```

второй:

```
@patch("apps.balance.services.intital_services.crypto")
```

В один прекрасный момент при запуске тестов, некоторые из них стали падать с ошибкой, причиной тому был декоратор patch. В тестах используются mock объекты, по какой-то неизвестной мне причине, в какой то момент времени объект который был "замокан" перестал вести себя так как указано ему в return_value параметре Mock объекта, а стал действовать как обычный объект выполняя настоящий свой функционал и возвращая ошибку при обращении ввиду отсутствия api ключа при вызове. Ниже привожу пример функций, рабочий и нерабочий вариант теста, отличаются они между собой только параметрами декоратора, также привожу структуру рабочего каталога. Другие тесты, что примечательно продолжают работать при указании полного пути начиная от директории apps в декораторе patch.

Неработающий вариант:

```
@patch("apps.balance.services.intital_services.TelegramNotifier", 
return_value=AsyncMock(TelegramNotifier))
@patch("apps.balance.services.intital_services.crypto")
def test_withdraw_manual_approve_with_error(self, mock_send, mock_telegram):
    mock_telegram.send_message = AsyncMock(return_value=None)
    mock_send.send = Mock(return_value={"error": "test"})
    mock_send.get_key_and_url = Mock(return_value=("", "", "crypto"))
    coin = self.create_coin(big_withdraw_checking=True)
    wallet = self.create_wallet(coin, amount=Decimal(10))
    data = {"address": wallet.address, "currency": coin.teaser, "withdraw_amount": Decimal(1), "user": self.user,
            "mix": False}

    WithdrawManager.proccess_withdraw(**data)
    withdraw = Withdraw.objects.filter(address='test').first()
    WithdrawManager.manual_approve(withdraw)

    self.assertBalanceCorrespondsAmount(amount=Decimal(10), wallet=wallet)
    self.assertWithdrawCreated(address=wallet.address)
    self.assertAutoWithdrawError(address=wallet.address)
```

Работающий вариант

```
@patch("balance.services.intital_services.TelegramNotifier", 
return_value=AsyncMock(TelegramNotifier))
@patch("balance.services.intital_services.crypto")
def test_withdraw_manual_approve_with_error(self, mock_send, mock_telegram):
    mock_telegram.send_message = AsyncMock(return_value=None)
    mock_send.send = Mock(return_value={"error": "test"})
    mock_send.get_key_and_url = Mock(return_value=("", "", "crypto"))
    coin = self.create_coin(big_withdraw_checking=True)
    wallet = self.create_wallet(coin, amount=Decimal(10))
    data = {"address": wallet.address, "currency": coin.teaser, "withdraw_amount": Decimal(1), "user": self.user,
            "mix": False}

    WithdrawManager.proccess_withdraw(**data)
    withdraw = Withdraw.objects.filter(address='test').first()
    WithdrawManager.manual_approve(withdraw)

    self.assertBalanceCorrespondsAmount(amount=Decimal(10), wallet=wallet)
    self.assertWithdrawCreated(address=wallet.address)
    self.assertAutoWithdrawError(address=wallet.address)
```

Структура проекта

[image: структура проекта]